# All radio is selected after click the single ion-radio in ionic3?

Tags: ionic3, radio-group

I will manage the ion-radio inside the loop in which we have to click the single radio all radio is selected instead of single radio.i want to get the single radio will be selected.i have tried Angular JS approch but it will be work but ion-radio value will be undefined.my html and ts code is?

```
 <ion-card *ngFor="let item of itemList">
     <ion-list radio-group  [(ngModel)]="chart">
     <ion-label>Present</ion-label>
       <ion-radio [color]="myColor" value="Present" (ionSelect)="toggleColor()">ID</ion-radio>
       <ion-radio [color]="myColor" value="Absent"  (ionSelect)="toggleColor()">Address</ion-radio>
       <ion-radio [color]="myColor" value="Leave"  (ionSelect)="toggleColor()">Name</ion-radio>
```

```js
Below our ts code:
  this.itemList = [{
      name : 'Harry',
      id :  101
    },
    {
      name : 'soni',
      id :  101
    },
    {
      name : 'deep',
      id :  101
    }]
}

toggleColor(item){

  if(this.chart == 'Present') {
      this.myColor = 'secondary';
  }  else if( this.chart == 'Absent') {
    this.myColor = "danger";
   } else {
     this.myColor = "danger";
   }
     this.itemList.every(function(chart) {
       return chart.Selected == true
     })  
  }
```

I have tried every function for manage the checkbox tell me what i am wrong here?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yqd1pr?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Comment: check it sir i have generated